# Order by two columns in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In a product table i have two columns like below special price and price.
The requirement is i have to sort the product based on the special price. if for a product, special price is 0.0 then normal price should be taken for sorting. if special price is not 0.0 then special price should be taken.I want a sqlite query for sorting. Kindly help me.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     special_price   |     price        |   product_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          550.0      |       699.95     |      1           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          0.0        |       260.0      |      2           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          250.0      |      332.66      |      3           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try ordering by a `CASE` expression which chooses the correct price for ordering based on your logic.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN special_price > 0 THEN special_price ELSE price END;
```